# Convert unique datetime format to date in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column of values with dates and times. Here's how it looks like:

```
example <- as.data.frame(c('1/3/23 20:00'))
colnames(example)[1] <- 'Time'
```

How can I convert it such that the output is only the date in the format `2023-03-01`? I've tried `as.Date` but it seems like I need to modify to suit the nature of my D/M/Y format.

Thank you!

Comment: assuming month/day/year: `as.Date(c('1/3/23 20:00'), "%m/%d/%y")`

Comment: The `%`-codes are listed (perhaps unintuitively) in [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).

Comment: Side question: why `as.data.frame` and `colnames`? Why not just `data.frame(Time=c('1/3/23 20:00'))` in one step?

Comment: @r2evans That is a much faster way! I didn't know that -- thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
time  <- "1/3/23 20:00"
dmy(time)
[1] "2023-03-01"
```